# Как взять данные из textarea в асинхронном запросе fetch

Tags: javascript, requests, get, асинхронность, fetch

Я хочу взять данные из текстового и отправить его текст в запросе GET запроса. Но он берет его пустым. Я не могу понять что не так, только начинаю разбираться в этом. Буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо!

```
var messageApi ='http://127.0.0.1:8080/user?login=';

'<label>Логин</label> <textarea name="login" id="login" > </textarea>


const getRequest = async() => {

console.log(document.getElementById('login').innerHTML.value);
    const response = await fetch(`${messageApi}${document.getElementById('login').innerHTML.value}`)
    console.log(await response.json());
    return await response.json;
};

        document.querySelector('.btn__login').onclick = function(){
            getRequest();
            // location.reload(); return false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы взять текст, введенный в `<textarea>`, вам нужно обратится к атрибуту `value`, данного элемента.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () =>
{
  console.log(document.querySelector('#login').value);
});
```

```html
<textarea name="login" id="login"></textarea>
<button>Получить значение</button>
```

Comment: И зачем используется `<textarea>`? Тут же самое логичное - `<input>`.